# Why isn't my code filling down?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim SLR As Range
Dim ELR As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next


Select Case UCase(Target.Value)

Case "START-LOCATION"
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    SLR = ActiveCell.Address
    Target.Offset(-1, 1).Select



Case "END-LOCATION"
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ELR = ActiveCell.Address
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(SLR, ELR).FillDown

End Select
End Sub
```

Hello all, I have the above code, it is supposed to set the variable on start location for the first cell, and on end location it sets the second variable and then fills down the cells from SLR to ELR, however it isn't working and isn't providing me with an error message, any ideas?

Comment: when is the code supposed to run? right now, you have it set to run when something on the worksheet changes, so it won't run until you make a cell value = "START-LOCATION" or "END-LOCATION"

Comment: @joseph4tw Thanks, this is the intended design.

Comment: where and what kind of error is raised

Comment: I see. When you clear contents for `SLR`, there is nothing to filldown. It will just clear all contents from `SLR` to `ELR` and copy formatting from `SLR` down to `ELR`. What do you want to fill down?

Comment: The immediate issue is that you're not disabling `Events`. When `Selection.ClearContents` gets called, it retriggers the `Worksheet_Change` event. You should disable events before and reenable after the select, using `Application.EnableEvents`

Comment: Next, your `Offsets` seem very odd. Thirdly, you're not actually providing us with any idea of what data you're trying to fill down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the followings:

```
SLR= Activecell.Address
```

into

```
Set SLR = Activecell
```

and do the same for ELR:

```
Set ELR = Activecell
```

Answer (score 0):

On Error Resume Next is always a bad idea.  If I was king of the world I would make this command illegal, the error handler should be for when something unexpected happens that crashes your code.

The most import thing with your macro is that the data the user gets at the end of it is correct.  If that means that when the code crashes and the user call you over then that's what it takes.  But having On Error Resume Next means that no one will ever know if your code has crashed and no one will ever know that the data is wrong.

Never ever use On Error Resume Next!!!!!

As for this bit of code you'll learn more about your problem if you remove On Error Resume Next.

Comment: Fortunately, you are not the king of the world. Actually, `On Error Resume Next` can be really useful when used with `If Err.Num <> 0` statement in some specific situations, but you're right when saying that this should be avoided in most cases.